# For embedded dbs, is the Db loaded to main memory in neo4j?

Tags: java, hadoop, neo4j

I was trying to parse a large file and create nodes for it in the neo4j db. I use map reduce and hence load the following line for every reduce call.

```
 GraphDatabaseService db = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(DB_PATH);
```

Now, this line gives me the following exception after running for some time-

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.muninn.MuninnPageCache.<init>(MuninnPageCache.java:230)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.pagecache.ConfiguringPageCacheFactory.createPageCache(ConfiguringPageCacheFactory.java:63)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.pagecache.ConfiguringPageCacheFactory.getOrCreatePageCache(ConfiguringPageCacheFactory.java:56)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.createPageCache(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:704)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.create(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:473)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:321)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:59)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:108)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:95)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:176)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:67)
    at com.kchakrab.BaseGraph.CreateBaseGraphReducer.reduce(CreateBaseGraphReducer.java:29)
    at com.kchakrab.BaseGraph.CreateBaseGraphReducer.reduce(CreateBaseGraphReducer.java:21)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:176)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:572)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:414)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:392)
```

So, can some one guide me as to what am doing wrong? Is the whole database loaded every time to the memory and the load for every reduce method is causing the GC overhead?

Comment: Stefan's answer is a good one - but to answer your question specifically -- no, the database isn't loaded into memory.  Stefan describes how memory is used and how you can tweak that, but when you create a an embedded database at a particular path, you're saving the DB to disk at that path, it's just a regular directory full of files.

Comment: Thats good to know. But, then why do I have the GC Overhead? Is it the transactions? Something must be filling up my memory. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Neo4j 2.2 uses by default up to 75% of your available RAM minus heap size for the [page cache](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/configuration-caches.html#_file_buffer_cache). Depending on your setup that might be too much.

You should tweak [`dbms.pagecache.memory`](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/configuration-settings.html#config_dbms.pagecache.memory) to a reasonable value.

Example: assume you have 16 GB RAM. The JVM defaults to 25 % (=4GB) heap size. From the rest (12GB), 75 % (=9GB) are used for page cache leaving 3 GB for OS and other applications. The default of 75% is a reasonable choice for server systems running only neo4j. If the machine does other stuff as well (desktop, other server processes) maybe set `dbms.pagecache.memory` to e.g. 5 GB.

JVM heap size can we configured in `neo4j-wrapper.conf`.

Comment: Thanks. I have 8gb RAM. So I set my JVM to 2G through command line (Xmx params) and my pagecache.memory in neo4j.properties to 2g. Its running now. Will take some time. Lets see how it turns out.

Comment: Ok. So, am still having troubles with this. I even tried to set the pagecache.memory to 1g. I still somehow always end up with a "GC overhead  limit exceeded". Any suggestions more?